# Prestashop Friendly URLs - Custom Module not showing up

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am trying to set up a custom module with my prestashop v1.6.1.7 install. It is fresh, and the module works (ie: it shows up on the front end and does what it needs to do). The issue is: I am trying to give that module a custom page where it can pick up `GET` variables to filter down a search.

I had this working in Prestashop v1.5.6.3 just fine.

Under the SEO & URLs - I don't have options for ANY module pages no matter what I do. It just shows the default pages.

[image: no modules listed.]

Is there something I can do to fix this so I can assign a specific URL to my module for it to be picked up?

Currently, this is the start of the code:

```
class filterbyjoshlistFrontModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController {
    public $php_self = 'cars';
```

How can I get this module to show up in the dropdown of the screenshot above?

Comment: Put this in your module `construct()` method. `$this->controllers = array('filterbyjoshlistfront');` and see if your controller shows up there.

Comment: @TheDrot Nope that doesnt work

Comment: What is your module name and controller file name?

Comment: @TheDrot filename: list.php and class name: filterbyjoshlistModuleFrontController

Comment: And module name is `filterbyjosh` right? So the line in module should be `$this->controllers = array('list');` and maybe temporary remove `$php_self`. Though your controller should be picked up immediatelly in SEO without any of this.

Comment: `$this->controllers = array(...` has to be present during installation, you can't just add it later.

Comment: @gskema Correct, I assumed it gets picked up on module instantiation since it's defined in `__construct()` but it actually is used only when module is installing controllers during module install.

Answer (score 1):

The name of the controller that you define within your module has to be like this:

class MODULE_NAMECONTOLLER_NAMEModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController

Please note that First letter in module name should be in Capital letter for example if your module name is supercheckout then the value of MODULE_NAME should be Supercheckout.

Same applies to CONTOLLER_NAME for example if your controller is checkout then value of CONTOLLER_NAME should be Checkout

And the file name of this controller file should be checkout.php and it should be present at the following path:

```
/modules/supercheckout/controllers/front
```